# Error 419 Page Expired. Laravel Yajra datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable, laravel-datatables

I'm trying to add a form button to delete a record, but for some reason the csrf token doesn't insert it. I've tried many ways but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm h-25 d-inline-block mr-3">Ver</a>
    <a href="{{ route('publicaciones.show', $id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm h-25 d-inline-block">Editar</a>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ url("publicaciones/{$id}") }}" class="col">
         @csrf

        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" id="eliminar">Eliminar</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Attached image :
[image: Capture]

Comment: Laravel version 7.0

Comment: Yes is blade code

Comment: try this once `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: I have already tried it and it does exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your route doesn't use web middleware. Make sure  you use `routes/web.php` for the route  and also make sure `RouteServiceProvider` has `Route::middleware('web')` example:

```
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')->namespace($this->namespace)->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

or you can add manually to each route use like bellow:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // your routes here

});
```

As commented on `RouteServiceProvider` web middleware will make your route receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.

Comment: I think the problem is not this, because the CSRF in any other view adds it and they have the same kind of routes.

I think the problem comes because this datatable uses ajax and for some reason I don't know, it doesn't insert the CSRF.

Comment: how you call the ajax route and where is it?

Comment: Excuse me. You're right. The datatable was loaded by an API route. I've already solved it thanks to your information. Thanks a lot!